# Extract Graph Data from image using openCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm pretty new to both python and openCV. I just need it for one project. Users take picture of ECG with their phones and send it to the server I need to extract the graph data and that's all.

Here's a sample image :

[Original Image Sample](https://pasteboard.co/JTM56dd.jpg)

I should first crop the image to have only the graph I think.As I couldn't find a way I did it manually.

[image]

Here's some code which tries to isolate the graph by making the lines white (It works on the cropped image) Still leaves some nasty noises and inacurate polygons at the end some parts are not detected :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')

kernel = np.ones((6,6),np.uint8)
dilation = cv2.dilate(img,kernel,iterations = 1)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(dilation, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#
ret,gray = cv2.threshold(gray,160,255,0)
gray2 = gray.copy()
mask = np.zeros(gray.shape,np.uint8)

contours, hier = cv2.findContours(gray,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for cnt in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 400:
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,
                                  0.005 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)
        if(len(approx) >= 5):
            cv2.drawContours(img, [approx], 0, (0, 0, 255), 5)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(gray2,gray2,mask)
cv2.imwrite('output.png',img)
```

[image]

Now I need to make it better. I found most of the code from different places and attached them togheter.

```
np.ones((6,6),np.uint8)
```

For example here if I use anything other than 6,6 I'm in trouble :frowning:
also

`cv2.threshold(gray,160,255,0)`

I found 160 255 by tweaking and all other hardcoded values in my code what if the lighting on another picture is different and these values won't work anymore?

And other than this I don't still get the result I want some polygons are attached by two different lines from bottom and top!

I just want one line to go from beggining to the end.

Please guide me to tweak and fix it for more general use.

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: I asked on open cv forums and they said it will takes a lot of effort to make this, I wanted to do this as a small project so I just gave it up, it's was too big.

Comment: yes i see your post there